# Play Framework DML insert script

Tags: playframework, playframework-evolutions

I am using Play Framework 2.3 with Slick and an in-memory H2 databse. When I start the application, I would like to not only create the database from the evolution script, but as well insert some default data. This topic doesen't seem to be covered in the Play documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a custom evolution script and place the DML in it. There is an activator template with this functionality – see the 2.sql file [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-computer-database-scala/tree/master/conf/evolutions/default).