# How does one run a SQL script before starting application with Slick?

Tags: playframework, slick, play-slick

Is there a way with Slick that you can run SQL code before the application starts or in the test set up like in Hibernate?

See example
https://github.com/geowarin/hibernate-examples/tree/master/standalone-data-jpa/src/main/resources

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Evolutions` in Play framework. If you are using `play-slick`, you can add `play-slick-evolutions` dependency and make sure  `play.evolutions.enabled` is not set to false in `application.conf`.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Evolutions

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlick

[UPDATE]

As per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689930/run-sql-before-starting-application-in-slick/34689966?noredirect=1#comment57126385_34689966), it looks like you want your SQL to be run on startup rather than with migration. If such then you can use [JavaGlobal](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaGlobal)/[ScalaGlobal](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal) for Play < 2.4. Else you can take look into [2.4 GlobalSettings doc](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings).

Comment: Thanks.  Evolutions are enabled.  I meant the data loading part.  Can I make a script that has Insert Into Table (Blah) Values (Blah, Blah Blah, 3) that Slick will look for and run before the application starts and after migrations.

Comment: You can try using `GlobalSettings` in Play framework.

Comment: I'm using play 2.4.  I'm still confused though.  Should I define a module with an eager binding to run the SQL script? How do I do that?   Also, how would you do this with just an sbt project that was using slick without Play?

Comment: If it was simple slick project, refer to hello-slick template. https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-hello-slick/blob/master/src%2Fmain%2Fscala%2FHelloSlick.scala

Comment: Ok.  That's adding data with scala code.  I was curious about adding data with an sql script specifically without having to write the scala code to do inserts.  I have an existing database that I can export with insert statements into my play application but I do not want to use the slick schema generation.  Do you know of a way to call an sql script to run within scala?

Answer (score 0):

My question is kind of a duplicate question.  See here
[Play Framework DML insert script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571498/play-framework-dml-insert-script).

With the play framework you only need to create a sql file in the evolutions directory called 2.sql with the insert statements that you need.

I'm still trying to figure out if you can do something like this without play in a stand alone sbt application.